# Variable class calling

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a class where I want to call different modules form it, depending on an input from the user.

In my mind it would look something like this:

```py
class Test:
   def test1:
       print("Hello world")

   def test2:
       print("farewell world")

user = input("> ")
Test.f{user}
```

Where it now will call what the user has told it to, but it doesn't work.
So my question is if it's possible, if it is then how I would accomplish it.

When trying examples from the given link, I keep encountering a problem for example where it tells me 
`"TypeError: test1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"`

when the input looks like so:

```py
getattr(globals()['Test'](), 'test')()
```

this is not the only one, and all I have tried leads to problems.
leading me to believe that either my problem is different, or I'm implementing it wrong.

Help with either scenario is much a appreciate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Comment: Sadly, I could not get them to work for my problem. But thank you for the help.

Comment: @TheVoidBeing please update your question with what you've tried from that link - as the question stands it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `getattr()`.
for example:

```
class Test:
    def test1():
        print("Hello world")

    def test2():
        print("farewell world")


userinput = input('Which function do you wish to call?\n')
# getattr() takes 2 parameters, class name, and attribute name.
myfunc = getattr(Test, userinput)
myfunc()
```

Comment: I don't know why this worked, when something simulere in the other answer's didn't. But this has solved my problem.